# Refreshing Fragment with ListView after theme change on container

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that I'm working on that uses the Twitter API. I have a list view of tweets inside of a Navigation Drawer activity that I added with Android Studio. I have another activity that I use for a settings activity, and on that activity the user can select the theme.

The problem I'm having is that when the user changes the setting and presses the back button, the theme of the container is changed, but not the fragment containing the list view. It's not until I restart the app that the proper theme is applied to the fragment.

However, if I use the back button on the action bar (up navigation) the theme is applied right away.

I'd like to come up with a way to apply the theme again right away when the user presses the back button (And the theme has actually been toggled), and so far this is what I've got:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case RETURN_TO_TWEET_LIST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

                if (bundle != null) {
                    boolean themeChanged = bundle.getBoolean(AppConstants.Strings.THEME_CHANGED);

                    if (themeChanged) {
                        refreshFragment();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void refreshFragment() {
    //TODO: Figure out how to get the list view to refresh when pressing back
}
```

I feel like the problem is not my Fragment code, as it works the way I would expect in one case, but no the other.

Here is the Navigation Drawer class:

```
public class CategoryViewSelector extends BaseActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private TwitterFeedFragment currentFragment;
private String fragmentName = "CUSTOM_FRAGMENT";
private CategoryManager categoryManager;
private final int RETURN_TO_TWEET_LIST = 2;
private SettingsManager settingsManager;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] drawerItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    categoryManager = new CategoryManager();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_view_selector);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    //create a fragment object palceholder
    TwitterFeedFragment fragment = null;

    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    //create a bundle object that will be used to pass arguments to the fragment
    //such as a category id.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            //load all the tweets by default.
            bundle.putLong("categoryId", position);
            fragment = new TwitterFeedFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            setCurrentFragment(fragment);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CategoryManagerView.class);
            //may have to change this to be for result again, so that you can use the onActivityResult method
            //which will prevent refreshing of the fragment.
            startActivityForResult(intent, RETURN_TO_TWEET_LIST);
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Help not yet available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            openFragmentForCategory(position);
            break;

    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, currentFragment, fragmentName)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

private void openFragmentForCategory(int position) {
    List<Category> categories = categoryManager.getAllCategories();

    //there are three default items in the list right now.
    //figure out a better way to handle this. Maybe an app constant.
    int index = position - 3;

    Category selectedCategory = categories.get(index);

    long Id = selectedCategory.getId();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    TwitterFeedFragment fragment = null;

    bundle.putLong("categoryId", Id);

    bundle.putString("categoryName", selectedCategory.getCategoryName());

    fragment = new TwitterFeedFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    setCurrentFragment(fragment);
}

/**
 * This method attaches a title to the fragment window when an item is clicked. This will also
 * require the use of the category names from the category manager.
 * @param number
 */
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.text_category_default_feed);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = "";
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.text_category_help);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category_view_selector, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RETURN_TO_TWEET_LIST);
            break;
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            currentFragment.refreshFeed();
            break;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            TwitterApplication.getRestClient().clearAccessToken();
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * This is required so that the refreshFeed method of any fragment can be called.
 *
 * In the future it might make more sense to make an interface.
 * @param currentFragment
 */
public void setCurrentFragment(TwitterFeedFragment currentFragment) {
    this.currentFragment = currentFragment;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case RETURN_TO_TWEET_LIST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

                if (bundle != null) {
                    boolean themeChanged = bundle.getBoolean(AppConstants.Strings.THEME_CHANGED);

                    if (themeChanged) {
                        refreshFragment();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void refreshFragment() {
    //TODO: Figure out how to get the list view to refresh when pressing back
}
```

}

Does anyone have suggestions on what I should be doing differently that would allow the fragment to have the correct theme when the back button is pressed? Please let me know if you would like to see more code, or have any questions.

I have tried detaching and attaching the fragment using the fragment manager, but I guess the theme of the fragment is never changed that way.

I'm also open to other suggestions for code improvement when they are spotted.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an Activity's theme in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()`.  And the fragment's theme is set during `onCreateView()`.

What do you mean when you say the container changes theme, but not the fragment?  I'm guessing this is what happens ... 
1) you go into the SettingsActivity to change theme 
2) The host Activity goes through `onStop`/`onCreate`, meaning it gets re-themed
3) but you have `setRetainInstance(true)` on the Fragment, meaning it does not get recreated.

If so, you have two options: remove `setRetainInstance`, or manually create a completely new Fragment (not just detach and re-attach) when you see that the theme has changed.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. I don't believe I've set anything to retain instance state, though. Sounds like recreating the fragment may be the way I have to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to detach then re-attach the fragment.
Otherwise you could call `invalidate()` on the specific views of your fragment.

Comment: Do you  mean that I would need to get the ListView from the fragment and call invalidate() on that?

Comment: Calling `invalidate()` on a view forces it to be redrawn. 
If your list is the only thing not being updated you could try that instead of detaching and re-attaching the whole fragment.
You still have that as a last option if all else fails.

Comment: It turned out that it wasn't a problem with the fragment necessarily, it had to do with the background color of my activity. I wrote some code that would set the theme of the Activity I was returning to - this worked to change the text color in the list view, but not the background. I ended up using a method from another SO Post that allowed me to get the background color of the current theme. I then had to set the background color on the layout to the new background color for everything to look the way I wanted. This was in addition to rebuilding the fragment.